# Parameter Value to select project number range

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have a parameter asking the user if they would like to "only" include project numbers below 5000.

If they say yes, then I need the parameter to adjust the project field to be <=5000.  If they say No, then the project number field should be <=99999999.

I am not sure how to accomplish this, right now I have a dataset where project number = @projnum, and I have @projnum parameter with two values of Yes and No.

I attempted to put an expression on the dataset properties under that specific parameter as:

```
=iif(Parameters!projnum.Value=1, <9999, <9999999999)
```

but I get a syntax error when using the `<` sign.  It will work with just a number.

Sorry, new to SSRS and cannot figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change your dataset query to use `<=`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ProjectNumber <= @projnum
```

Then adjust your parameter values to the range values:

[image: new parameter values for @projnum]

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my issue, I was overthinking it just a bit.  I appreciate your efforts on this matter!